# CRUD operations in ASP.NET MVC through Entity Framework Code First Approach using stored procedures?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework. I have assignment of performing CRUD operations using EF code-first approach via stored procedures. I had tried it in a database-first approach and succeeded, but in a code-first approach, I've been stuck for the past week.

I've searched on google but everywhere examples are so much complicated for me. Please do explain in easy and simple. For example we have a `StudentInfo` table with columns Id, Name, Age and Roll Number available for CRUD operations.

How to perform CRUD operation on this table using a code-first approach via stored procedures in ASP.NET MVC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/CRUD-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: I've tried it.  But in vein

Comment: When I search I get [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468673(v=vs.113).aspx) and [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/code-first-insert-update-delete-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx). If something isn't making sense ask a specific question and include some code on what you tried.

Comment: can u give a simple example on my question?
SteveGreene